# System.InvalidCastException: Column 'modifiedbyuserid' is null

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I had been getting an error

> System.InvalidCastException: Column 'modifiedbyuserid' is null

when using Entity Framework Core with a Postgresql database, even though the column is defined as nullable `int?` in the model.

Database: Postgresql version 12.3-1.pgdg100+1

.NET Core project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CreateDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
    ModifiedDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
    "Disabled" BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT False,
    CreatedByUserID BIGINT,
    ModifiedByUserID BIGINT
);
```

Model in C#:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public long Userid { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Createdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modifieddate { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public long? Createdbyuserid { get; set; }
    public long? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
}
```

C# call to get the database row

```
var user = Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(
                u => u.Username == model.Username
            );
```

Error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Column 'modifiedbyuserid' is null

StackTrace

```
System.InvalidCastException: Column 'modifiedbyuserid' is null.
   at Npgsql.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidCastException_NoValue(FieldDescription field)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetInt64(Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method750(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at lambda_method751(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at BusinessLogic.Repository.Implementations.LoginRepository.Login(LoginRequest model) in BusinessLogic/Repository/Implementations/LoginRepository.cs:line 61
   at API.Controllers.LoginController.Login(LoginRequest model) in API/Controllers/LoginController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method741(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at API.Middleware.JwtMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in API/Middleware/JwtMiddleware.cs:line 41
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 2):

In .net 6.0, Either you need to use nullable property like section 2 below (which you did) or you need to disable nullable globally in propertyGroup section in project file like below (section 1):

**Section 1:**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
       ...
       ...
       ...
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

> If you disable `Nullable` Property globally in project level then you
> dont need to use nullable (using ?) property in entire project

**Section 2:**

```
public long? Modifiedbyuserid { get; set; }
```

> Null-state analysis and variable annotations are disabled by default
> for existing projects—meaning that all reference types continue to be
> nullable. Starting in .NET 6, they're enabled by default for new
> projects.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the project file from nullable "enable" to nullable "disable".

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I don't really see how nullable reference types being enabled or disabled would affect nullable value types. Are you sure this was the cause of your problem? Could you provide the full exception and stack trace in your question (when the exception appears in the debugger, click "copy details")?

Comment: Sorry for the massive necro, but I've encountered the same issue with an older version of EF Core and disabling nullable reference types doesn't seem to have anything to do with this issue. My project didn't have them enabled in the first place, actually. Additionally, setting IsRequired(false) on the IEntityTypeConfiguration for that entity (either in the navigation, the ID, or both) had no effect. My suspicion is there is a bug in Npgsql EF Core package that doesn't treat self joins correctly.